# Convert PDF to PDF/A-1

Tags: pdf, pdfa

I know this probably is not strictly a programming-question (well maybe it is, i don't know) but i'm having serious problems trying to convert a regular pdf (with hyperlinks, bookmarks, images, embedded fonts etc.) into a PDF/A-1 format.

I get all kinds of errors when i check it with pdfaPilot.

How can i prepare a pdf so no problems will occur when i try to convert to PDF/A-1.
Most problems can be fixed with pdfaPilot but apparently not all.

One of the problems i get is with the XMP Metadata which are "not properly defined".
Wat exactly does this mean, and can i do something to prevent this.

Another one is: "Syntax problem: Array with more than 8191 elements" (i hope this one is solvable)

I hope someone can help me out here, since i'm in a tight spot right now with deadlines that are killing me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert to PDF/A and check compliance under Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464539/convert-to-pdf-a-and-check-compliance-under-linux)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experiences this kind of problem before.

I use [OpenOffice pdf viewer plugin](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/pdfimport) together with [Jodconverter 2](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) to convert existing PDF to PDF/A. Jodconverter is a python/java/CLI library which you can use to convert document. It uses OpenOffice to convert documents.

Comment: Can you share how do you use Jodconverter 2 to convert existing PDF to PDF/A ? I have been reading the documentation but could not find how to do it. Thanks.